# Weka Decision Tree not working on real data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-mining, weka

I'm trying to make human activity recognition using the iOS accelerometer and gyroscope. The feature that I use are mean, variance, standard deviation, energy and cross-domain entropy. If I provide Weka with a test set of, let's say, 30% of the total data, it gives me an accuracy of 98.7%.
But when I implement the J48 decision tree in my application, the decision tree literally doesn't work and it doesn't classify activities correctly (the precision is near 0%), although I'm taking samples the same way that I take samples for the test set. The same data used for classification in the app gives incorrect results in the app but a 98% precision in weka. How is this possibile? Maybe I'm implementing the decision tree the wrong way?

[image]

I simply read the decision tree this way: if Var(Gravity.z) is less or equal than 47572.90768, then I check Energy(GravityMag) and if it's less or equal than 31250.004174, then I check Energy(UserAcc.y) and so on... since Weka assumes that if the difference between two numbers is smaller than 10e-6, I multiplied all numbers for one million so the precision goes up to 10e-12, and I double checked that I'm also correctly multiplying the values to be used by the in-app classifier so that couldn't be the problem. If the precision on the test set is high it couldn't be overfitting so I really don't know what to think.